# Probability of being in same connected component

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, asymptotics, random-graphs

I would like to answer the following basic question:

Let $V$ be a collection of $n$ vertices and fix $x$ and $y$ in $V$. Let $G$ be a random graph on $n$ vertices and $M$ edges. What is the probability that $x$ and $y$ belong to the same connected component?

I've tried doing this by hand and I can not get anywhere with it. It seems like such a basic question to ask that I'm sure its been done in the literature somewhere but I can not find it. My thoughts now lead towards random graph theory and asymptotic probabilities.

I'd be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly is random here? Is $G$ fixed and we choose $x,y$ uniformly at random? Or is $G$ also a random graph, for example $G \in \mathcal G(n,p)$, where $\mathcal G(n,p)$ is the class of Erdös-Renyi graphs?

Comment: @Stefan, $G$ is random here and it belongs to the model $\mathcal{G}(n,M)$. I've edited the question so it should be more specific.

Comment: @coffeemath, that is part of the question. Not only how many connected components there are but also how large they are.

Comment: You can deduce the answer, in a form that's probably nearly as strong as possible, from known information about the [giant component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_component) of random graphs.

Comment: @ChrisCave Got it. Will delete my comment.